# Read contents of files on s3 bucket without downloading

Tags: python, r, amazon-s3

I am quite new to aws and s3 so pardon if this looks like I haven't tried anything. I want to traverse the directories and files, read the files and retrieve specific lines from the publicly accessible s3 bucket: `s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/` without downloading it. I want to just be able perform basic tasks like `grep/cat` on the file contents.

For e.g. I should be able to get lines containing `MYCN` from all the files and folders on the s3 bucket.

What is the most efficient way to do it? Are there packages in R/Python that can help traverse s3 buckets?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/38910315/2191173 solves the question that how to read a file's content without downloading it

Answer (score 0):

http://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/s3_tut.html

```
conn = boto.s3.connection.S3Connection(
        aws_access_key_id='xxx',
        aws_secret_access_key='yyy'
)
for key in conn.list(prefix='logs/*.log'):
    print key
```

Comment: And how, precisely, does this answer the questIon?