# Is it possible to get the contents of an S3 file without downloading it using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am working on a process to dump files from a `Redshift` database, and would prefer not to have to locally download the files to process the data.  I saw that `Java` has a `StreamingObject` class that does what I want, but I haven't seen anything similar in `boto3`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have a `mybucket` S3 bucket, which contains a `beer` key, here is how to download and fetch the value without storing it in a local file:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
print s3.Object('mybucket', 'beer').get()['Body'].read()
```

Comment: good solution but . can we do that if file is bigger than our RAM size . .(Or can i search a word in 100gb file in s3 , where my system is having 1gb RAM and 20 gb HDD)

Comment: @yunus for that, you'll need to use streaming apis.

Comment: If you want to use a client, you can also do `s3 = boto3.client('s3')

print(s3.get_object(Bucket='mybucket', Key='beer')['Body'].read())`

Answer (score 2):

`smart_open` is a Python 3 library for efficient streaming of very large files from/to storages such as **S3**, GCS, Azure Blob Storage, HDFS, WebHDFS, HTTP, HTTPS, SFTP, or local filesystem.

https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/

```
import boto3
import smart_open

client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
                      aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                      aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY,
                      )
url = 's3://.............'
fin = smart_open.open(url, 'r', transport_params={'client':client})

for line in fin:
    data = json.loads(line)
    
    print(data)
    
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be relevant to what you want to do, but for my situation one thing that worked well was using tempfile:

```py
import tempfile
import boto3
    
bucket_name = '[BUCKET_NAME]'
key_name = '[OBJECT_KEY_NAME]'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(key_name, temp.name)
# do what you will with your file...
temp.close()
```

Comment: In my case, I was trying to download a csv file from s3 and read it using csv reader. Your solutions worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: This solution downloads the file, I believe the original answer was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I use that solution, actually:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def get_content_from_s3(bucket: str, key: str) -> str:
  """Save s3 content locally
     param: bucket, s3 bucket
     param: key, path to the file, f.i. folder/subfolder/file.txt
  """
  s3_file = s3_client.get_ojct(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read()
  return s3_file.decode('utf-8').strip()
```